# method that takes a class as a template parameter, and takes the parameters of the classes constructor as method parameters

Tags: c++, templates, entity

Okay so I'm creating my very own Entity-Component System, and I'm stuck at the AddComponent Entity method, which adds components to the Enity, here is how it looks:

```
template <typename T>
void AddComponent() {
    NumOfComponents++;
    AllComponents.push_back(new T());
}
```

this works fine, but what if i have a Component constructor ? Like so

```
class Transform : public Component
{
public:
    Transfrm(Vector3f newPosition, Vector3f newRotation, Vector3f newScale) : Component("Transfrm") {};

    Vector3f Position;
    Vector3f Rotation;
    Vector3f Scale;
    ~Transfrm();
};
```

What I'm trying to achieve is something like this:

```
Entity ent1;
Vector3f Pos, Rot, Scl;
ent1.AddComponent<Transform>(Pos, Rot, Scl); // This is currently not possible
```

How do I accept Transform's method parameters as AddComponent method parameters, and achieve something like that above ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the most simplest use case for a parameter pack.

```
template <typename T, typename ...Args>
void AddComponent(Args && ...args) {
    NumOfComponents++;
    AllComponents.push_back(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

Requires at least C++11.

Comment: hello the code you showed me is giving me two errors at line 24 which is 'void AddComponent(Args && ..args) {'                                                       Error C3484 syntax error: expected '->' before the return type 24 
Error C3613 missing return type after '->' ('int' assumed)    24

Comment: Small typo. One period was missing.

Comment: nevermind fixed it, replace "..args" with 3 dotted args: "...args"